# Has TurfCutter been abandoned?

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home

I managed to get the TurfCutter extension installed using the command line and the menu item shows up, but it's not working.  It hasn't been updated in two years, so maybe it doesn't work with newer versions of CiviCRM?  Is anyone using TurfCutter? Has it been abandoned? I emailed the developer, but no reply yet. Are there programmers we can hire to fix it?  I'm using current versions of CiviCRM and WordPress.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/turfcutter

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofrRT1Lmatg

https://gitlab.com/asludds/civicrm-turfcutter

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you need to accomplish, you can get a similar function from the proximity search in civi under Search - Custom Searches - Proximity Search.

If you haven't already you'll need to set up geocoding/mapping in core: `https://{your-site}/civicrm/admin/setting/mapping?reset=1`